# spring websocket sockjs connection lost before established

Tags: spring, websocket, sockjs

i have a problem when using spring websocket with sockjs over stomp..
when i define **"localhost:8080/websocket"** its working perfectly...
but when i change the localhost with the ip . ex: **192.168.3.56** the websocket wont connect to the backend.. and there is message **"Connection Lost before established"**
anybody can help me ,  i am really stuck..

its my spring configuration websocket code :

```
@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
    config.enableSimpleBroker("/device","/topic","/queue");
    config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");

}

@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/websocket").withSockJS()

            .setStreamBytesLimit(512 * 1024)
            .setHttpMessageCacheSize(1000)
            .setDisconnectDelay(30 * 1000);
    ;
}
```

and its my client code based on coffeescript:

```
 service = {}


listener = $q.defer()
  socket =
    client: null
    stomp: null

  service.RECONNECT_TIMEOUT = 30000
  service.SOCKET_URL = "#{HOST}websocket"
  service.SUBSCRIBER_UPDATE = "/device/update"
  service.SUBSCRIBER_UPDATE_ALL = "/device/update_all"

  reconnect = ->
    $timeout (->
      initialize()
      return
    ), @RECONNECT_TIMEOUT
    return

  startListener = ->
    socket.stomp.subscribe "#{service.SUBSCRIBER_UPDATE}/#{id}", (data) ->
      body = JSON.parse(data.body)
      if body.message is 'RELOAD'
        $state.transitionTo $state.current, $stateParams,
          reload: true
          inherit: false
          notify: true
      return
    socket.stomp.subscribe service.SUBSCRIBER_UPDATE_ALL, (data) ->
      console.log data
      body = JSON.parse(data.body)
      if body.message is 'RELOAD'
        $state.transitionTo $state.current, $stateParams,
          reload: true
          inherit: false
          notify: true
      return
    listener.resolve()

  errorListener =(error)->
    listener.reject()

  service.initialize = ->
    socket.client = new SockJS(service.SOCKET_URL)
    socket.stomp = Stomp.over(socket.client)
    socket.stomp.connect {}, startListener,errorListener
    socket.stomp.onclose = reconnect
    listener.promise
  service
```